# working properly with the server and client side, how to do it?

Tags: angular, laravel, web

I'm getting some errors on the web server side, but the problem is that I can see this errors only sometimes. I'm working with angular and laravel. So well, on the ngOnInit() metodh I fill up 3 select options and I do other validations.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isAvailableCheckBoxToGenerate();
  this.onLoadComboIncidents();
  this.onLoadComboExpt();
  this.onLoadComboCC();
  this.onLoadPerson();
}
```

Here is a print pant of the interface

[image]

So, all the above methods do the same like this:

```
onLoadComboIncidents(){
   this.ccService.getcc().subscribe((data) =>{
   this.cc = data;
  });
 }
```

each select combo has around 350 records.
the errors I get sometimes are these :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/apirestregistro/public/api/centrojudicial' from 
>        origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow- 
>        Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed.

another error is:

> "message": "Server Error"

but the error is not always the same, but the most of time the app working right. I don't know if the information i'm populiating on the client side is extensive and the server breaks it so the rest of methods crash too

Comment: do you own the serverside? what platform are you using for it? what is the CORS configuration?

Comment: Looks like a CORS issue to me. Can you add proxy config in your app and try that? [Proxy config](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing [CORS issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) depends on what webserver you're using.

You'll need to allow cross-origin requests on your server.